# Change label font in ArcGIS Online or Portal

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-online-webmap

We are looking to change the font for labels in a webmap we have published to ArcGIS Portal, but there is no option to change the font. Is this not possible, or is it something we need to do with the layer before publishing it?

Comment: try converting your labels to annotations on desktop then upload the annotation feature class, it should respect the font you chose on the desktop environment. I dont believe you can adjust fonts in AGOL web maps directly.

Comment: I have the same question and no answer yet...